# Estou com problema para mostrar a pagina pelo Vue.js usando o Electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, electron

quando eu fui abrir o app pelo `electron` a pagina não abriu e quando fui exibir pelo console ele mostro o seguinte erro:

> "[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the
>   template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates
>   into render functions, or use the compiler-included build."

o codigo é esse aqui

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Photon</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/photon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="window">
      <!-- Common layout -->
      <header class="toolbar toolbar-header">
        <h1 class="title">Loja Casa e Construção</h1>
        <div class="toolbar-actions">
          <div class="btn-group">

            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="icon icon-home"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="icon icon-folder"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default active">
              <span class="icon icon-cloud"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="icon icon-popup"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="icon icon-shuffle"></span>
            </button>

          </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="icon icon-home icon-text"></span>
              Filters
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-dropdown pull-right">
              <span class="icon icon-megaphone"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="window-content">
        <div class="pane-group">
          <div class="pane-sm sidebar">
            <p>
              Agora vai sentar, Vai sentar, vai sentar
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="pane">
            <button type="button" @click="createClient()" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastro de Clientes</button>
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    Nome
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    CPF
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Telefone
                  </th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="cliente in clientes">
                  <td>
                    {{cliente.nome}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{cliente.cpf}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{cliente.telefone}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click=editClient(cliente)>Editar</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="toolbar toolbar-footer">
        <h1 class="title">
          Developer by Antony de Lara
        </h1>
      </footer>
    </div>
      <div id="modal" v-if="openModal">
        <div class='wrap'>
          <form action="" class="pane-body" id="cadastro-cliente">
            <h3 v-if="mode=='cadastro'">
              Cadastro de Cliente
            </h3>
            <h3 v-if="mode=='edicao'">
              Editar de Cliente
            </h3>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" v-model: "client.nome" placeholder="Nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" v-model: "client.cpf" placeholder="CPF" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone" v-model: "client.telefone" placeholder="Telefone" />
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-positive" @click="clientStoreOrUpdate()" id="salvar">Salvar</button>
            <button type="Button" class="btn btn-negative" @click="openModal=false">Cancelar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </body>
  <script>
    /*import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    import App from './components/App.vue';
    import Home from './components/Home.vue';*/
    var read = require('read-file-utf8')
    var loki = require('lokijs');
    var db = new loki('db.json')
    var data = read(__dirname + '/db.json');
    db.loadJSON(data);
    window.Vue = require('vue');
    //console.log(read(__dirname+'/db.json')); //¹
    var clientes = db.getCollection('clientes');
    //console.log(db);
    new Vue({
      el: 'body',
      data: {
        clientes: [],
        mode: '',
        client: {
          nome: '',
          cpf: '',
          telefone: ''
        },
        openModal: false
      },
      ready: function () {
        this.clientes = clientes.data;
        console.log(this.clientes);
      },
      methods: {
        editClient: function (client) {
          this.mode = 'edicao';
          //alert('Abrindo Editar');
          this.openModal = true;
          this.client = client;
        },
        createClient: function () {
          this.mode = "cadastro";
          this.openModal = true;
          this.client = {
            nome: '',
            cpf: '',
            telefone: ''
          };
        },
        clientStoreOrUpdate: function () {
          if (typeof this.client.$loki != 'undefined') {
            clientes.update(this.client);
          } else {
            clientes.update(this.client);
          }
          db.save();
          this.openModal = false;
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</html>

renderer.js

// This file is required by the index.html file and will
// be executed in the renderer process for that window.
// All of the Node.js APIs are available in this process.
var loki = require('lokijs');
var db = new loki('db.json')
var clientes = db.addCollection('clientes');

/*
clientes.insert({
    nome:'Jao',
    email: 'contato@jaodasilva.com'
});
db.save()
*/

function ready(fn) {
    if(document.readyState != 'loading'){
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
}
ready(function () {
    //Body ..
    document.querySelector('#salvar').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert('OK'); //¹
        let data = {
            nome:document.querySelector('#nome').value,
            cpf:document.querySelector('#cpf').value,
            telefone:document.querySelector('#telefone').value
        };
        //console.log(data); //² 
        clientes.insert(data); //³
        db.save();
        alert('Salvo com sucesso')
        document.querySelector('#cadastro-cliente').reset()
    })
})
```

Comment: Você está usando o webpack para empacotar tudo isso, certo? Por favor poste também as configs do webpack.

Comment: eu posso mandar tambem o repositorio pelo github? é que são muitos pacotes

Comment: https://github.com/tonydallara/tcc-projeto-electron